# Как подгрузить фотографию через url в бота,что бы при сообщении отправлялось еще и фото

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно что бы при `/start` отправлялось сообщение и фото
код уже сам есть,но не получается загрузить само фото

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os
site = 'qiwi.com/n/NEFFYXXX1337'
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])                                                                                       
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Аренда номеров", callback_data="number")
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Proxy/VPN", callback_data="vpn")
    keyboard.add(button1,button2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Добро пожаловать в Sakura Service!\nВыберите нужный вам раздел',reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os
site = 'qiwi.com/n/NEFFYXXX1337'
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Аренда номеров", callback_data="number")
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Proxy/VPN", callback_data="vpn")
    keyboard.add(button1,button2)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption='Добро пожаловать в Sakura Service!\nВыберите нужный вам раздел',reply_markup=keyboard)
```

В photo нужно указать id или ссылку на само фото.